# SignalR push notification when users are not online

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signals

I need to implement push notifications for my asp.net core project.For a news service

it needs to work in such a manner that if the user is not online while a message is being sent out, then the message will arrive at the client when they are online thenext time.

All the articles I can find about this, are all slightly vague about this case, and just emphasises the "real-time" communication.
So would it be possible to have push notifications that could that wiht signalr?

Comment: There’s nothing in SingalR that does this. It’s just a transport channel. You’ll need to handle storing things yourself and then showing them when a user is online.

Comment: Oh ddamm, do you think I will have to have some sort of persistence to do this? or could I store this in-memory?

Comment: If you don’t need them to be persistent across restarts etc you can do it in memory. If you need persistence across restarts you’ll need something more.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have a really dumb question also if it is okay. When I have a lot of users connected to the same solution, could I then also have access to the same memory? So I could have one single event that could trigger that several users could be sent a notification, when they were back online again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it needs to work in such a manner that if the user is not online while a message is being sent out, then the message will arrive at the client when they are online thenext time.

To achieve your above requirement, you can try:

1. mapping user to the connection id(s) and persist that mapping, which would help find/get new connection id(s) based on user name or email etc readable info after user connect/reconnect to hub, then you can send unread message/data to specific user by specifying connection id(s).

   Note: you can also send a message to a specific user by passing the user identifier to the `User` function in a hub method, please refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#users-in-signalr
2. for unread messages, as @SamiKuhmonen mentioned, you can store/persist those messages in somewhere, and if you want to persist information after restarts or you would host hub on multi-servers/instances, in-memory store is not a good approach. You can try to store messages in database etc permanent, external storage.
3. define and use a flag to indicates if the message has been seen by user. After client received a message, then invoke a hub method to update that flag or delete that message from the store.