# ASP.NET Core web notification implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For the intranet company, I want to send to user web notification. This notification could be general (new feature in the intranet) or for a specific user (a task is ready to pick up or an import is completed).

I started to use `SignalR` but the user receives the notification only if the intranet is open. So, I'm looking around to implement a different web notification and I saw some posts:

- https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-a-browser-in-asp-net-core/
- https://labs.bawi.io/web-push-notifications-through-vapid-method-7d4d6927a006
- https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/12/push-notifications-and-aspnet-core-part.html
- https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/

I can't find an end-to-end implementation in ASP.NET Core. On [GitHub](https://github.com/tpeczek/Demo.AspNetCore.PushNotifications) I found a few projects but again when I close the browser, I can't receive the notification.

I can't find any Microsoft documentation for that. Can you point me in the right direction please?

### Update

The idea is:

- Setting up a minimal PWA
- Subscribe to Push Notifications
- Send Push Notifications
- Receive Push Notifications
- Show Push Notifications

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the intranet is open"? Do you mean it only works when they have the web page open?

Comment: Yes, only if the browser is open

Comment: I'm not sure any browser supports sending notifications if it's closed, I could well be wrong though

Comment: Is your project hosted on Azure? search google for azure push notification service, it is simple to use.

Comment: No, my project is on promise in the company webfarm

Comment: So the problem is that browser not showing notificatians when closed?

Comment: Exactly! I saw in this post https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-a-browser-in-asp-net-core/ a partial implementation but I don't know how they manage VAPID (https://tools.reactpwa.com/vapid). I saw this project on GitHub https://github.com/vip30/WebPush-NetCore but it is 4 years old

Comment: `I started to use SignalR but the user receives the notification only if the intranet is open.` You can try to store/persist those messages in somestore, such as database etc, and then you can send these unread messages to user once that specific user is reconnecting to hub. This SO thread discussed a similar issue, you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054434/signalr-push-notification-when-users-are-not-online